# awk case insensitive and boolean operator

Tags: awk, operators, case-insensitive

I would like to grep lines that contains both patterns in any order and I'm using

```
awk '/pattern1/ && /pattern2/' file.txt
```

but if I want to do case insensitive search, adding /i works only if I add it to pattern2.

```
awk '/pattern1/ && /pattern2/i' file.txt ...works

awk '/pattern1/i && /pattern2/i' file.txt ...don't, outputs the whole file
```

anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
awk '{s=tolower($0)} s~/lowercase_pattern1/ && s~/lowercase_pattern2/' file
```

There is also the possibility of the `IGNORECASE` option in GNU awk..

---

You could also most of the time do something like this:

```
grep -Ei 'pattern1.*pattern2|pattern2.*pattern1' file
```

Comment: I wasn't downvoting it, it's by mistake. Now I can't change my vote, because my vote is locked.
Thanks for answer.

Answer (score 3):

`awk '/pattern1/ && /pattern2/i' file.txt`  will ignore the pattern `/pattern2/`

if you want to ignore the case totally add `IGNORECASE = 1`.

ie.

`awk 'BEGIN {IGNORECASE = 1} /pattern1/ && /pattern2/' file.txt`

Answer (score 2):

You could also use `grep`:

```
grep -i "pattern1" file.txt | grep -i "pattern2.txt"
```

Though it won't be as efficient as it uses two passes to find the lines.

You could use `sed` which would do it in one pass:

```
sed '/pattern1/I!d;/pattern2/I!d/' file.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

just change your command to :

```
awk 'tolower($0)~/pattern1/ && tolower($0)~/pattern2/' your_file
```

alternatively ,you can use perl:

```
perl -lne 'print if(/pattern1/i and /pattern2/i)' your_file
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also make the `regex` itself case-insensitive, and do range patterns like

---

```
mawk '/[Mm]/, /[Qq]/'
```

---

```
M
N
O
P
Q
m
n
o
p
q
```